# How to append an input value to a list in a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input, append

I'm trying to append a value entered by the user to list in a dictionary, but it shows error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Can anyone find out the mistake?

```py
Dict = {} # an empty dictionary to be filled later

Dict["SomeKey"] = []

Dict["SomeKey"] = input ("Enter a value: ") # it works

Dict["SomeKey"].append(input("Enter another value: ")) # This part gives me error !!!
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: That's a string for you... (`input` returns a string)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use it like so:

```py
dict["SomeKey"] = [input ("Enter a value: ")]
dict["SomeKey"].append(input('Yet again...'))
```

Because the function `input` returns a string which means `dict["SomeKey"]` is also a string which doesn't have the `append` function.

Comment: but this will delete the first input data ... I need to append the newly entered data to the previous one!

Comment: Edited to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This trace back will help you to resolve your problem.

```py
>>> Dict = {}
>>> Dict["SomeKey"] = []
>>> type(Dict["SomeKey"])
list
>>> Dict["SomeKey"] = input ("Enter a value: ")  # in here you are change `list` to `str`
Enter a value: 123
>>> type(Dict["SomeKey"])
str
```

So the error is correct `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`. `append` is available on `list`.

```py
>>> 'append' in dir(str)
False
>>> 'append' in dir(list)
True
```

So if you want to keep `Dict["SomeKey"]` as a `list`, just change it like which you already did in your last line.

Answer (score 0):

I have written following code and it works fine as long as you already have that "SomeKey" in dictionary and you are entering the user inputs in double quotes.

```
Dict = {}
Dict["SomeKey"] = []
Dict["SomeKey"].append(input("Enter another value:"))
Dict["SomeKey"].append(input("Enter another value:"))
print Dict

O/P
sankalp-  ~/Documents  python p.py                                                                                                            
 ✔  2027  00:59:30
Enter another value:"SomeValue1"
Enter another value:"Somevalue2"

{'SomeKey': ['SomeValue1', 'Somevalue2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the previous part of your example you set `Dict["SomeKey"]` to a string.

Let's say that you typed in "foo" for the entry in step 3 in your example, then `Dict["SomeKey"].append("another_string")` (I used "another_string" as the result of what you might have typed for the input). Then, this becomes "foo".append("another_string). But "foo", a string, does not have an `.append()` method.